# Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;\nJoin Inner

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I wanna join 2 streams but I received the next error and I don't know how to fix it:

> Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations
>   on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;\nJoin Inner

```
df_stream = spark.readStream.schema(schema_clicks).option("ignoreChanges", True).option("header", True).format("csv").load("s3://mybucket/*.csv")
display(df_stream.select("SendID", "EventType", "EventDate"))
```

[image]

I wanna join df1 with df2:

```
df1 = df_stream \
              .withColumn('timestamp', unix_timestamp(col('EventDate'), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa").cast(TimestampType())) \
              .select(col("SendID"), col("timestamp"), col("EventType")) \
              .withColumnRenamed("SendID", "SendID_update") \
              .withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "timestamp_update") \
              .withWatermark("timestamp_update", "1 minutes")

df2 = df_stream \
              .withColumn('timestamp', unix_timestamp(col('EventDate'), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa").cast(TimestampType())) \
              .withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes") \
              .groupBy(col("SendID")) \
              .agg(max(col('timestamp')).alias("timestamp")) \
              .orderBy('timestamp', ascending=False)

join = df2.alias("A").join(df1.alias("B"),  expr(
      "A.SendID = B.SendID_update" +
        " AND " +
        "B.timestamp_update >= A.timestamp " +
        " AND " +
        "B.timestamp_update <= A.timestamp + interval 1 hour"))
```

Then finally when I write the result in append mode:

```
join \
.writeStream \
.outputMode("Append") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "s3://checkpointjoin_delta")  \
.format("delta")  \
.table("test_join")
```

I received the previous error.

> AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 join.writeStream.outputMode("Append").option("checkpointLocation",
>   "s3://checkpointjoin_delta").format("delta").table("test_join")
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py in table(self,
>   tableName)    1137         """    1138         if
>   isinstance(tableName, basestring):
>   -> 1139             return self._sq(self._jwrite.table(tableName))    1140         else:    1141             raise TypeError("tableName can
>   be only a single string")
>
> /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>        67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the **.groupBy**, it's necessary to add the timestamp. For example:

```
df2 = df_stream \
              .withColumn('timestamp', unix_timestamp(col('EventDate'), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa").cast(TimestampType())) \
              .withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes") \
              .groupBy(col("SendID"), "timestamp") \
              .agg(max(col('timestamp')).alias("timestamp")) \
              .orderBy('timestamp', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Wxactly what I wanted. I missed adding timestamp to the `.groupBy`.

Comment: why does it need to have timstamp in the group by too?