# Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, autoload

I have the problem with `Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations`. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267347/append-output-mode-not-supported-when-there-are-streaming-aggregations-on-stream) I need to add the `modifiedon` in my `groupby` statement in the below code like this

`agg = df.groupBy("id","modifiedon").agg(max("modifiedon").alias("modifiedon"))`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
df = df.dropDuplicates()
df = df.withWatermark("modifiedon", "1 day")
agg = df.groupBy("id").agg(max("modifiedon").alias("modifiedon"))
final =df.join(agg, on=["id", "modifiedon"], how="inner")
dfUpdates = final.withColumnRenamed("id","BK_id")
```

But this creates the problems as the `final` still contains duplicated `Id`s in it. Since I dont add that column in groupby,later I have the problem to do a `merge into` delta table.

```
final.writeStream.format("delta").foreachBatch(update_insert).option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory).trigger(availableNow=True).start("abfss://bronze@datalake01p.dfs.core.windows.net/D365/msdyn_workorder_autoloader_nodups")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to give timestamp type column in group by either with `window` function or timestamp column,
but in your case you can not give `modifiedon` column even though it is of type timestamp because you are requirement is to do aggregate on `modifiedon` column itself.

So as I mentioned earlier use window with a greater number of days which you are sure that comes under range of your data.

Here, I used 20000 days.

```
agg = df.groupBy(window("modifiedon","20000 day"),"id").agg(max("modifiedon").alias("modifiedon"))
final =df.join(agg, on=["id", "modifiedon"], how="inner")
```

and output.

```
final.writeStream.format("delta").option("checkpointLocation", "/csv_chk_pnt/").start("/out_csv/final/")
```

[image]

Give large number of days for very long old records, may be even 50000 days also.